# R RJDBC Oracle - select from table with date field

Tags: sql, r, oracle, date, rjdbc

I'm writing some queries on `R`, using `RJDBC` to connect to an `Oracle database`.
Everything is working fine, except when Dates come into play.

I created a table where two fields are based on R objects Date. As I later learned, given RJDBC implementation these fields on the database became VARCHAR. I then create new fields casted as Data

```
   alter table TEMPIDENTIFIERS add DataHigh2 as (cast(DataHigh as Date))
   alter table TEMPIDENTIFIERS add DataLow2 as (cast(DataLow as Date))
```

Later, I want to interact with this table and do some filters on Date fields.
I run a test query like

```
   select distinct * from TEMPIDENTIFIERS where DataHigh2 > DataLow2
```

Now, for the crazy part. From some locations (say, my personal PC, both from `R` and from `SQLDeveloper`) everything works fine. However, from the server I'm suposed to work from, the query crashes with

> Error in .verify.JDBC.result(r, "Unable to retrieve JDBC result set
>   for ",  : 
>         Unable to retrieve JDBC result set for select distinct * from         TEMPIDENTIFIERS where DataHigh2 > DataLow2  (ORA-01861: literal does
>   not match     format string
>       )

Now, I understand that the problem must lie somewhere in the server, and so the system administrator should be the one solving it. However, everything else works fine, leading me to think that I should be able to fix it myself.

Comment: Try select * from NLS_SESSION_PARAMETERS
where PARAMETER = 'NLS_DATE_FORMAT'; to see if any differences between your local environment and the server.